# Redirect an iFrame when it is clicked by the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, frame

How do I redirect the iFrame to an another html web page, when it is clicked by the user?

The iFrame is actually an html page.When I click on the iFrame, I want it to redirect to an another html page.

**My code:**

```css
         h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
         }
         h2{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            
         }
         body {   
            background-color: #feb236;
         }
         iframe {
            border: 2px solid black;
         }
         body{
             height: 175vh;
         }
         div{
            border-width: 0 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 400px;
            left: 400px;
            z-index: -1;
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Plagiarism</title>
      <h1><u>PLAGIARISM</u></h1>
      <div></div>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2 style=>What is Plagiarism?</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe width="400" height="250"></iframe></p>
      <h2>What is Plagiarism in Computer Science?</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe width="400" height="250"></iframe></p>
      <h2>Famous Cases of Plagiarism</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe width="400" height="250"></iframe></p>
      <h2>Punishment for Plagiarism in US</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe width="400" height="250"></iframe></p>
   </body>
   
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test IFrame SRC by Javascript </title>

<script>
function RedirectPage()
{
 document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://WWW.microsoft.com";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
     <iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" value="Change IFrame sRC Location" name="btnRedirect" runat="server" onclick="RedirectPage()"/>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This code maybe can help you.